# How to update gitlab Merge Request build status (pipeline status) when using Jenkins and the pipeline was previously canceled/deleted?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci

We set up Gitlab with Jenkins integration, by using Jenkins Gitlab plugin and trigerring Jenkins webhooks (regular Pipeline type job) on gitlab Merge Request events (configured in Gitlab->Repo->Integrations) and we are successfully displaying the job build status on the Merge Request page (by using updateGitlabCommitStatus in the pipeline) - it is displayed as a status of some pipeline, which as I understand, is created and associated with the last commit in the source branch.

At some point, I canceled this pipeline from the MR page and after that, closed and reopened the MR, thus re-triggering the build.

Unfortunately, after cancelling the pipeline, the latest build job statuses were not reflected nor in the MR, nor in the pipeline itself. In the pipeline page it wouldn't even display the newest jobs running in jenkins.

I tried deleting this specific pipeline (via curl - we are using gitlab 12.3, which doesn't allow deleting pipelines via GUI) and creating a new Merge Request (same branch, same commit), hoping that a new pipeline would be created in this case, but nothing. It seems that I have no means to display build status again for this specific commit.

Any suggestions how to overcome this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case and the only way to do this is to re-run the pipeline from GitLab... You have to enter to the integrations and there you should look for all request sent to the Jenkins. Once you locate the correct one, you click on resend and it should give you the correct status.

For my observations, the update GitLab status command only work when it is invoked from a webhook.